# watchdog daemon unable to reset hardware watchdog timer on Supermicro X9DR3-F motherboard

Tags: debian, watchdog

I have a [Supermicro X9DR3-F motherboard](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/C606_602/MNL-1259.pdf) where `JWD` jumper pins 1 and 2 are shorted and watchdog functionality in UEFI is enabled:
[image: Supermicro UEFI]

This means that the system is reset after around 5 minutes if nothing resets the hardware watchdog timer. I installed the [`watchdog`](http://www.crawford-space.co.uk/old_psc/watchdog/watchdog-configure.html) daemon and configured it to use `iTCO_wdt` driver:

```
$ cat /etc/default/watchdog 
# Start watchdog at boot time? 0 or 1
run_watchdog=1
# Start wd_keepalive after stopping watchdog? 0 or 1
run_wd_keepalive=1
# Load module before starting watchdog
watchdog_module="iTCO_wdt"
# Specify additional watchdog options here (see manpage).
$
```

When the `watchdog` daemon is started, then the driver is loaded without issues:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep iTCO_wdt
[   17.435620] iTCO_wdt: Intel TCO WatchDog Timer Driver v1.11
[   17.435667] iTCO_wdt: Found a Patsburg TCO device (Version=2, TCOBASE=0x0460)
[   17.435761] iTCO_wdt: initialized. heartbeat=30 sec (nowayout=0)
$
```

Also, the `/dev/watchdog` file is present:

```
$ ls -l /dev/watchdog
crw------- 1 root root 10, 130 Dec  8 22:36 /dev/watchdog
$
```

`watchdog-device` option in `watchdog` daemon configuration points to this file:

```
$ grep -v ^# /etc/watchdog.conf 



watchdog-device    = /dev/watchdog
watchdog-timeout   = 60


interval           = 5
log-dir            = /var/log/watchdog
verbose            = yes
realtime           = yes
priority           = 1

heartbeat-file     = /var/log/watchdog/heartbeat
heartbeat-stamps   = 1000
$
```

In order to debug the writes to the watchdog device I have enabled `heartbeat-file` option and looks that the keepalive messages to `/dev/watchdog` are sent:

```
$ tail /var/log/watchdog/heartbeat
 1575830728
 1575830728
 1575830728
 1575830733
 1575830733
 1575830733
 1575830733
 1575830733
 1575830733
 1575830733
$
```

However, despite this the server resets itself with roughly five minute intervals.

My next thought was that maybe the `iTCO_wdt` driver controls the watchdog in [C606 chipset](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/63986/intel-c606-chipset.html) and the watchdog resetting the server is instead part of IPMI. So I made sure that the `iTCO_wdt` driver is not loaded during the boot and rebooted the server. Fair enough, the `/dev/watchdog` was no longer present. Now I loaded the `ipmi_watchdog` module:

```
$ ls -l /dev/watchdog
ls: cannot access '/dev/watchdog': No such file or directory
$ sudo modprobe ipmi_watchdog
$ sudo dmesg -T | tail -1
[Tue Dec 10 21:12:48 2019] IPMI Watchdog: driver initialized
$ ls -l /dev/watchdog
crw------- 1 root root 10, 130 Dec 10 21:12 /dev/watchdog
$
```

.. and finally started the `watchdog` daemon which based on the `/var/log/watchdog/heartbeat` file is writing to `/dev/watchdog` with 5s interval. In addition, one can confirm this with `strace`:

```
$ ps -p 2296 -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      2296     1  0 01:28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/watchdog
$ sudo strace -y -p 2296
strace: Process 2296 attached
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted nanosleep ...>) = 0
write(1</dev/watchdog>, "\0", 1)        = 1
write(1</dev/watchdog>, "\0", 1)        = 1
open("/proc/uptime", O_RDONLY)          = 2</proc/uptime>
close(2</proc/uptime>)                  = 0
write(1</dev/watchdog>, "\0", 1)        = 1
write(1</dev/watchdog>, "\0", 1)        = 1
write(1</dev/watchdog>, "\0", 1)        = 1
write(1</dev/watchdog>, "\0", 1)        = 1
write(1</dev/watchdog>, "\0", 1)        = 1
nanosleep({5, 0}, NULL)                 = 0
write(1</dev/watchdog>, "\0", 1)        = 1
write(1</dev/watchdog>, "\0", 1)        = 1
open("/proc/uptime", O_RDONLY)          = 2</proc/uptime>
close(2</proc/uptime>)                  = 0
write(1</dev/watchdog>, "\0", 1)        = 1
write(1</dev/watchdog>, "\0", 1)        = 1
write(1</dev/watchdog>, "\0", 1)        = 1
write(1</dev/watchdog>, "\0", 1)        = 1
write(1</dev/watchdog>, "\0", 1)        = 1
nanosleep({5, 0}, NULL)                 = 0
write(1</dev/watchdog>, "\0", 1)        = 1
write(1</dev/watchdog>, "\0", 1)        = 1
open("/proc/uptime", O_RDONLY)          = 2</proc/uptime>
close(2</proc/uptime>)                  = 0
write(1</dev/watchdog>, "\0", 1)        = 1
write(1</dev/watchdog>, "\0", 1)        = 1
write(1</dev/watchdog>, "\0", 1)        = 1
write(1</dev/watchdog>, "\0", 1)        = 1
write(1</dev/watchdog>, "\0", 1)        = 1
nanosleep({5, 0}, ^Cstrace: Process 2296 detached
 <detached ...>
$
```

`watchdog` daemon above with PID `2296` was started in a way that `heartbeat-file` option in `/etc/watchdog.conf` was commented out in order to reduce the `write` system calls in the output of `strace`.

However, the server still reboots with roughly 300s intervals.

Why isn't the watchdog daemon able to reset the hardware watchdog timer on Supermicro X9DR3-F motherboard?

Comment: From another SuperMicro FAQ: disable the Watchdog function in BIOS, OS and BMC first :
BIOS : Advanced >> Power Configuration >> Watch Dog function >> Disabled
OS : `echo 0 >> /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog`

IPMI : smcipmitool <30> <97>

Data1: enable/disable, 0-disable, 1-enable

Data2: expire time, count by minutes (minute unit). Then just use only either nmi or ipmi.

Comment: @ssnobody Thanks! I also read that Supermicro FAQ ID `26478`, but isn't this essentially asking one to disable that BIOS watchdog function altogether? If yes, then shouldn't there be a way to reset that BIOS watchdog from the OS? Or how should one use BIOS watchdog if there is no way to reset its timer from the OS?

Comment: Does strace show the watchdog daemon writing to /dev/watchdog? Are there any errors associated with the write?

Comment: @icarus Good idea! `Strace` shows that the `watchdog` daemon writes to `/dev/watchdog` with 5s interval and there seems to be no errors. I added the output of `sudo strace -y -p <watchdog_pid>` to my initial post.

Comment: @Martin yes, its asking to disable the watchdog in BIOS, but apparently that doesn't stop it from using nmi or ipmi watchdog functionality. I would agree that if they provide a "watchdog", there should probably be some way to reset it from the OS or they should rename it "Rebooter" instead of "watchdog". The post over at https://serverfault.com/questions/695650/supermicro-bmc-watchdog-caused-reboots has another suggestion for you though if you want to try to keep the BIOS watchdog enabled and use it.

Comment: For reference, the suggestion is "just leave watchdog jumper (JWD1) open with neither NMI nor hard-reset selected. Watchdog is enabled in BIOS settings"

Comment: @ssnobody When I leave the pins 1 and 2 of `JWD` jumper on my Supermicro X9DR3-F motherboard open and have `Watch Dog Function` in BIOS `Enabled` and have `watchdog` daemon in OS **not** running, then the motherboard does not reset. Basically, leaving the `JWD` jumper open has the same affect as having the `Watch Dog Function` in BIOS `Disabled`.

Comment: In addition, as user [Terry Kennedy writes in servethehome.com forum](https://forums.servethehome.com/index.php?threads/supermicro-x9scm-f-powers-off-every-5-minutes.10164/), the BIOS seems to be able to reset the BIOS watchdog. In other words, the system is not reset if `Watch Dog Function` in BIOS is `Enabled` and one stays in the BIOS. Or maybe the BIOS `Watch Dog Function` is temporarily deactivated as long as one stays in BIOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason watchdog daemon was not able to reset the hardware watchdog timer on Supermicro X9DR3-F motherboard is that the watchdog functionality in UEFI controls the **third** watchdog. This is on Winbond Super I/O 83527 chip. In other words, `iTCO_wdt` and `ipmi_watchdog` drivers were wrong drivers for that watchdog chip.

Answer (score -1):

On a A2SDi-4C-HLN4F, I had to use `bmc_watchdog` (from `freeipmi`) to get it to work.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Would you mind adding some more explanation on how to start/configure/use that watchdog?

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).